# why does batch file execute different lines than what it contains

Tags: batch-file

i typed this line in a bat file (pause just to see what got typed)

```
    start my_program -m y -f %s_%d_fix -z n
    pause
```

it ends up running this

```
    start my_program -m y -f d_fix -z n
```

as you can see the %s_% part gets removed
i tried looking for wether the % caused reading the lines differently but it's just fine when typing in cmd
the launched program gets incorrect arguments, any thoughts on this? thanks.

Comment: What do you have in `s`? Looks like it's empty.

Comment: the program reads %s it as series name, such as %t is current time %d is description etc ... and adds up parts to make the file name (referred by -f) seriesname_date_fix

Comment: if the program is using those as options, put them in quotes or escape the `%` with another `%`: `%%s_%%d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Cmd and MS-DOS Command.com use `%` to indicate environment variables. In your case, `%s_%` is interpreted as a variable expansion (with `s_` acting as the variable's name), and is expanded to an empty string.

To preserve the `%` sign unaltered, use `%%s_%%d_fix`.

Comment: i cant thank you enough. been 2hours trying to find a solution, Thanks a lot